# Rails has_many :through polymorphic relationship not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following three models:

Event:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings, as: :taggable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

events table:

Column   |  Type    |                     Modifiers
---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
id       | bigint   | not null
title | string | not null
content | text | not null
```

Tag:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destory
  has_many :events, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Event'
end

tags table:

Column   |  Type    |                     Modifiers
---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
id       | bigint   | not null
name | string | not null
```

Tagging:

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :tags
end

taggings table:

Column   |  Type    |                     Modifiers
---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
id       | bigint   | not null
taggable_id | integer | not null
taggable_type | string | not null
tag_id | integer | not null | FK_INDEX
```

Now the problem is I can't seem to use any of these relationships and getting errors indicating no associations exist.

```
event = Event.find(x)
event.tags

Error: 
NameError: uninitialized constant Event::Tags

event.taggable

Error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `taggable' for #<Event>
```

I can't figure out if my associations are setup right or my use case is wrong?

How would I add an assocation through the mode?
How would I query tags through Event model?

Comment: I think in `Tagging` you might need `belongs_to :tag` (singular)

Comment: @mrrogers you're right but a bit to cautious. The name of `belongs_to` and `has_one` assocations should **always** be be singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple pluralization error:

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

The names of `belongs_to` and `has_one` associations should **always** be singular.

If you look at the error message `NameError: uninitialized constant Event::Tags` you can see that its looking for `Tags` and not `Tag`.